# When I click on my link to access an uploaded PDF, I am not getting the correct one

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have a table books that can have only two records. This table will always store only two PDFs.

One PDF corresponds to a PDF book of 1st class. Other PDF corresponds to a PDF book of 2º and 3º class. And I have an administrative panel where I can update these two PDFs.

To update these PDFs I need to select a class (1º class or 2º and 3º class) in a dropdown, and I need also to select a PDF in my input file that corresponds to book for selected class.

If doesn't exists yet a record for selected class, I will do an insert, else I will do an update. (basically just the first time I´ll do an insert)

**The problem I'm having is:**

I'm uploading my PDFS with success in my books folder,and when I open PDFs in my books folder I get access to correct PDF.

But then I have below my input file two links to my two current PDFs, and when I click to acess each pdf Im not getting the correct pdf, Im getting an old PDF that I used primarily for testing,  and now I do not even have in my project directory.

Is really strange, I'm not understanding this situation, it seems that I'm always accessing a PDF file that is saved in cache or something, but in my books folder when I open uploaded PDFs, are always the correct PDFs.

And when I acess my developer tools my links for PDFs have the correct path: `<a style="margin-right:10px;" href="../../uploads/books/2014/07/1_class.pdf"  title="Pdf of book of 1st class">Se current book of 1st class.</a>`

Do you see why this can be happening? This is my code in my books file:

```
<div>
<?php
    //First I see if user submit my form
    if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
        //I store class that users chooses (can be 1º class or 2º and 3º class)
        $f['class'] = $_POST['class'];   
        //I get a title depending of each selected class   
        $title = ($f['class'] == '1' ? '1º class' : '2º and 3º class');
        //I see if there are empty fields
        if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){
            echo 'Please fill all fields';
        }
        //If all fields were submited I Will upload selected pdf
        else{
            if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){
                $folder = '../../uploads/books/';
                $year = date('Y');
                $month = date('m');
            if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){
                mkdir($folder.$year,0755);
            }
            if(!file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month)){
                mkdir($folder.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
            }
            $f['class'] = ($f['class'] == '1' ? '1_class' : '2_3_classs');
            $pdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
            $ext = substr($pdf['name'],-3);
            $name = $f['class'];
            $f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$name.'.'.$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$f['pdf']);
            }
            //If already exist a pdf book for selected class I will do an update with last selected pdf
            $readBooks = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE class = ?");
            $readBooks->bindParam(1,$f['class'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $readBooks->execute();
            $resultBooks = $readBooks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($readBooks->rowCount() >=1){
                $updEmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE books set title = ?, pdf =?, class=?, WHERE class = ?");
                $updBook->bindParam(1,$title);
                $updBook->bindParam(2,$f['pdf']);
                $updBook->bindParam(3,$f['class']);
                $updBook->bindParam(4,$f['class']);
                $updBook->execute();
                echo 'Book inserted with sucess';
            }
            //If dont exist a pdf book for selected class I will do an insert with last selected pdf
            else{
                $insEmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO books (title, pdf, class) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                $insEmt->bindParam(1,$title);
                $insEmt->bindParam(2,$f['pdf']);
                $insEmt->bindParam(3,$f['class']);
                $insEmt->execute(); 
                echo 'Book inserted with sucess';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form name="editpost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--I have a field to select class--> 

        <!--And then I have a field to select my book pdf:-->    
        <div class="label">
            <span class="field">Book pdf:</span>
            <input type="file"  name="pdf" accept="application/pdf" />
            <?php
            $readB = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from books");
            $readB->execute(); 
            //below this field I want to show the current book for 1st class and for 2nd and 3rd class  
            echo '<div class="viewcapa">';
                while($resultBook = $readB->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
                    echo '<a style="margin-right:10px;" href="../../uploads/books/'.$resultBook['pdf'].'"';
                            echo 'title="Pdf book of '.$resultBook['title'].'">';
                            echo 'See current book '.$resultBook['title'].'';
                    echo '</a>';
                }
            echo '</div>';  
            ?>                              
        </div>  
        <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="sendForm"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your "new" file have the same filename as the "old" file? If so, it may be a cache issue as you suggested. Have you tried clearing your browser cache? A way round this issue may be to timestamp the filenames in some way.

Comment: Thank you user 3371942. The problem was really that, and your solution, giving some id to my uploaded file seems to work. You can give your answer so I can accept. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your "new" file have the same filename as the "old" file? If so, it may be a cache issue as you suggested. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

A way round this issue may be to timestamp the filenames in some way.

(previous answer became comment?)